# Screen crash in Lubuntu and Xubuntu both but works fine with Windows Xp

Tags: lubuntu, 15.10, screen, crash

Windows XP works fine on my desktop of almost 8 years old having 512 mb ram and intel 2.6 ghz processor. I switched into Lubuntu but the screen crashes if I open it's software centre or browse the internet. It also crashes while opening multiple files at once. Can anyone help to fix this?
The screen is okay while small memory tasks are done but the screen crashes eventually .

Comment: What version of Lubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 15.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Lubuntu you are using died (reached End of Life) yesterday: (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2016/07/28/ubuntu-15-10-wily-werewolf-end-of-life-reached-on-july-28-2016/)

Given you only have 512MB of Ram I would suggest installing Lubuntu 14.04 or Xubuntu 14.04 instead of their 16.04 counterparts.

If I were you I'd buy a new used computer for a couple hundred dollars that was 100 times better than your current setup and could run Ubuntu 16.04 / 16.10.

Comment: Actually I am trying to make this computer run smoothly and donate to charity.So Can you suggest lighter than Lubuntu but a bit heavier than puppy Linux?

Comment: Lubuntu 14.04 should be lighter than Lubuntu 15.10.